# Is there a way to share a QGIS plugin for some users, not every QGIS users?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I need to make a PyQGIS plugin for a client, but we have some specific connection to a database. I did a plugin before only for me so I used QGIS plugin reloader. Now I need it to be on other desktop.

My questions are:

- If I put my plugin on the qgis repo, do I have any way to make it only usable for the client
- What are the other options I have if not?

Comment: create your **own** repository is an option ... i can't answer for the other options ...

Comment: You can host your own repository. Your clients add this repository to their QGIS client. Open the plugins dialogue and look at Settings. https://gis-ops.com/qgis-3-plugin-tutorial-set-up-a-plugin-repository-explained/ has an example.

Comment: you can offer a zip file with your plugin anyway over any platform. The user should then use in the "manage  and Install Plugin" Dialog the option "Install from ZIP". To provide a ZIP just zip the folder with your plugin in it.

Comment: @eurojam I'll use your way, so my question is answered ! Do you want to post it as answer so I can close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can offer a zip file with your plugin anyway over any platform. The user should then use in the "manage and Install Plugin" Dialog the option "Install from ZIP". To provide a ZIP just zip the folder with your plugin in it.

[image]